# Правильно ли составлено предложение с союзом "и"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать именно так:"Этот предмет себя напрочь изжил и вселяет во всех окружающих только ужас"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно.

Союз "и" соединяет однородные глаголы (*изжил и вселяет*) - запятая не ставится.

Изжить себя - становиться ненужным, не находить применения, **выйти из употребления**, **устареть**.
*От маленьких деталей и до важнейших вопросов многое в русской армии держалось на изживших себя традициях, а не на здравом смысле* (А. Игнатьев. Пятьдесят лет в строю).

То есть предмет вышел из употребления и устарел, в связи с чем сильно ухудшился его внешний вид - теперь выглядит ужасно и страшно. Возможно, о старых кораблях, машинах.

Интересно, о каком именно предмете идёт речь.

Answer (score 1):

Что касается правописания — да, можно.